# Hibernate JCache 5.4.3.Final doesn't work with JCache 5.4.2.Final configuration

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jcache

I am using JCache with Hibernate like :

```
    <!-- JCache -->
    <!-- https://medium.com/@skywalkerhunter/org-hibernate-orm-deprecation-caa816ba2755 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jcache</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache-transactions</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.1</version>
```

In the `application.yml` i have among others the following :

```
#JPA
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
    #database-platform=com.letner.lx.auditing.MySqlDialect
    properties:
      javax.persistence.validation.mode: none
      hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache: true
      javax.persistence.sharedCache.mode: ENABLE_SELECTIVE
      hibernate.cache.region.factory_class: jcache
      hibernate.javax.cache.provider: org.ehcache.jsr107.EhcacheCachingProvider
      hibernate.jdbc.batch_size: 1000
      hibernate.order_inserts: true
```

It worked successfully until now with version :

```
<artifactId>hibernate-jcache</artifactId>
<version>5.4.2.Final</version>
```

After passing version `<version>5.4.3.Final</version>` i am getting the following error :

```
.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.cache.spi.RegionFactory]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1778)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1105)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:67)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:139)
    at com.intralot.iif.core.SpringBootRunner.run(SpringBootRunner.java:11)
    at com.intralot.l10.sepa.app.SepaAdaptorApplication.main(SepaAdaptorApplication.java:46)
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.cache.spi.RegionFactory]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl$MetadataBuildingOptionsImpl.<init>(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:688)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.<init>(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources.getMetadataBuilder(MetadataSources.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:218)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:167)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:51)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1837)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1774)
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Unable to resolve name [jcache] as strategy [org.hibernate.cache.spi.RegionFactory]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.selectStrategyImplementor(StrategySelectorImpl.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:212)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:169)
    at org.hibernate.cache.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator.resolveRegionFactory(RegionFactoryInitiator.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.cache.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator.initiateService(RegionFactoryInitiator.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.cache.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator.initiateService(RegionFactoryInitiator.java:32)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
    ... 30 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [jcache]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:354)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.selectStrategyImplementor(StrategySelectorImpl.java:129)
    ... 37 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : jcache
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl$AggregatedClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:342)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:351)
    ... 38 common frames omitted
```

I didn't changed nothing except the **minor** `<version>` what am i missing ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is looking for a full class name and the shortcut string "jcache" doesn't work for that property anymore. Can you try instead setting:

```
hibernate.cache.region.factory_class: "org.hibernate.cache.jcache.internal.JCacheRegionFactory"
```

Comment: I am getting `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : org.hibernate.cache.jcache.internal.JCacheRegionFactory` , i would give +1 and mark as answer but i get this error :)

Comment: Then to me it feels like you are missing something in the dependency chain. I would check your dependencies and make sure nothing is getting overridden. According to the hibernate docs, the string "jcache" should still work.